# Grails Redirect being called but page is not being rendered

Tags: grails, redirect, twitter-bootstrap, controller, modal-dialog

Good afternoon friends.

I've been struggling with an extremely frustrating problem for the last few days and am finally at the end of my rope. Everyone in my team that has had a little bit of time cannot seem to figure out the issue either and it's driving me insane!

Anyway, I have a Controller with a delete action that is called when a user confirms deletion from a Bootstrap modal dialog. The action gets called and the redirect statement gets hit in debug just fine. It even shows the call in chrome developer tools as being called!

But, for some reason, the page never redirects. I've even tried explicitly redirecting to Google with no other code in the action. I have no idea what the deal is. I'll post any relevant code; let me know if there's other code that you may require.

***CatalogController.groovy***

```
def delete = {
    def catalog = Catalog.get(params.id)
    if (catalog == null) {
        redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'dashboard')
        println "Catalog is null and cannot be Deleted"
        return
    }

    if (request.method == "POST") {
        //catalog.deleted = true TESTING UNTIL REDIRECT WORKS 
        if (catalog.validate()) {
            userService.addUserActivity("Deleted catalog " + catalog.title, catalog.class.getName(), catalog.id, null)
            flash.notice = "Catalog has been deleted"
            catalog.save()
            println "Catalog successfully deleted"
        }
        else {
            flash.error = "There was an error marking the catalog deleted"
        }

        redirect(controller: 'home', action: 'dashboard')
        return
    }

    [ catalog: catalog ]
}
```

***Bootstrap Modal markup***

```
<div id="deleteDialog" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Catalog</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><strong>Are you sure you want to delete this Catalog?</strong></p>

        <div class="dialogInnerInfo">
            <div class="row-fluid control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="catalogNumber">Catalog Number:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label id="catalogNumber" >${catalog.legacyId}</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${catalog.id}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="catalogTitle">Catalog Title:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label id="catalogTitle">${catalog.title}</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="catalogTitle">Number of Samples:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label id="catalogTitle">${catalog.sampleCount}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
            <g:remoteLink class="btn btn-primary" controller="catalog" action="delete" id="${catalog.id}" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</g:remoteLink>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" value="${catalog.id}" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'delete', controller: 'catalog', params: '\'id=\'  + this.value')}">Click Here</button>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried all sorts of different buttons (g:links, buttons, g:remoteLinks, etc.) and cleaning up the delete action as well. I've also tried deleting my browser cache, grails cache, running grails-clean and a sleu of other tasks to see if the issue is in my environment but others don't get the redirect either.

Please forgive the ugly coding, it'll be cleaned up once the redirect works. I also welcome suggestions and improvements :)

Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

Comment: You need to remove all those return statements and you should be good to go.  The last statement in your controller needs to either be a redirect or render (or implied render with just the model map).

Comment: I think he uses a `return` to stop the subsequent code from executing, after a redirect has been called.

Comment: I've tried removing the return statements and it doesn't have any effect. GalmWing is correct in that the returns are to keep the rest of the code from being hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently shown version cannot work since a remotelink will not do a redirect since the response is parsed from JS. You would need to take care of it manually in the JavaScript or take a g:link.

Additionally you cannot use `data-dismiss="modal"` in combination with links, because twitter bootstrap will intercept your click and prevent any further server communication. If you remove data-dismiss="modal", it will work.

Comment: g:link doesn't cause a redirect either. Unless my code is wrong:
<g:link class="btn btn-primary" controller="catalog" action="delete" id="${catalog.id}" data-dismiss="modal">Link</g:link>

Comment: you cannot use `data-dismiss="modal"` in combination with links, because twitter bootstrap will intercept your click and prevent any further server communication. if you remove `data-dismiss="modal"`, it will work.

Comment: Thank you, Crudolf! Your suggestions put me on the right path! Here's the code that got it working correctly!

`<div class="modal-footer">
  <g:form action="delete" method="post" controller="catalog">
   <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${catalog.id}"/>
   <g:actionSubmit class="btn btn-primary" value="Action" action="delete"></g:actionSubmit>
   <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
   </g:form>
  </div>`

The other buttons were not working because they were rendering AJAX which got handled behind the scenes. No wonder why it wasn't rendering in the browser...